# Черный список. Или хоть что-нибудь подобное

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено

Интересует, нет ли какой возможности предупреждать, от кого идут "личные сообщения"? По сути это комментарии, но когда один и тот же человек с одним и тем же доводом "хочет тебя" во всех постах, это надоедает. А "фонарь" загорается при любом таком комментарии - и без указания на авторство...

Answer (score 3):

С такими пользователями должны разбираться модераторы. В то же время комментировать пользователи с низким рейтингом могут только свои посты и ставить имя с помощью @ можно только на того пользователя который уже отвечал на комментарии к этому вопросу или ответу.

Так что избежать лишних комментариев можно не оставляя своих комментариев, а общаться только через модераторов (флажки), или с помощью голосования за/против.

Comment: Ясно... чего-то не хватает или в интерфейсе или в организации, короче.

Comment: Artemix, я все-таки чего-то недопонимаю... Какой тогда смысл защищать вопросы и главное - наставлять новичков на путь истинный, если реально ни наука не впрок, ни защиты от пободного вандализма - никакой?! На старом ресурсе (хэшкоде) я пусть и ценой нескольких своих банов вандалов таких останавливал. А тут?

Comment: Ох, про вандализм - это я два своих вопроса объединил. Но в принципе, оно и тут уместно. Речь-то об одном и том же персонаже.

Comment: Главное отличие бета-версии сайта от "нормального" - активное сообщество пользователей. Пока складывается впечатление что активных пользователей, следящих за порядком на сайте очень мало. Когда их достаточно - сомнительные посты быстро уходят в "минус", и скрываются для новых пользователей, а их авторы (по сумме некачественных постов) со временем получают автоматический бан.

Comment: да там же клоны (мульты)  плодятся как тараканы. Самыми активными они будут, если дустом не побрызгать.

Comment: А потом вы не учитыаете, что "бета" здесь только движок и оболочка. Контент и пользователи перехали с хэшкода. Вилимо, при перезде потерялась б**о**льшая и лучшая часть личного состава (кроме нескольких бойцов топ-уровня).  Как же хорошо у вас на rus.SE... Я даже скромничаю там что-то писать. Чтобы не испортить своим "хранцузским".

Comment: А вообще, вы знаете, увидел, что это ситуация привлекла внимание админа. Пусть оно так и будет, не стоит нагнетать. Спасибо за разговор!.

Comment: Russian.Stackexchange действительно поупорядоченнее выглядит. Но здесь и посетители, и объемы другие: вопросов почти в 6 раз больше, а кол-во посещений в день - в 14 раз больше. Что же касается посетителей - там в основном англоговорящие иностранцы, не слишком уверенные в своем знании языка, а здесь - знающие русский с рождения и уверенные в себе. Так что здесь действительно модерация сайта - задачка посложнее.